VIF/GVIF for binary logistic regression
How do I decide if there is multicollinearity or not in my logistic regression? Specifically, the GVIF OR GVIF^(1/2*Df). How much is the maximum value of GVIF to indicate the multicollinearity?
Reglog_JKK <- glm(JKK ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7 + X8 + X9, 
                family = binomial)
vif(Reglog_JKK)

Results below:
        GVIF Df GVIF^(1/(2*Df))
X1  3.411006  1        1.846891
X2  4.899361  1        2.213450
X3 31.723130  5        1.412985
X4 19.833157  3        1.645250
X5  4.305749  1        2.075030
X6 12.188838  3        1.517028
X7  5.436424  2        1.526962
X8  2.525105  1        1.589058
X9  3.045529  1        1.745144


Before getting to the VIF/GVIF, you have a lot of predictors in your model. I would ensure that 1) they are theoretically relevant and 2) you have enough data to estimate this model. But that is a separate issue.
As to the VIF, there isn't really a theoretical maximum, though various cutoffs have been proposed. A common cutoff that may be useful is a VIF/GVIF of around 10 (Miles, 2014). One can then investigate where the inflation is coming from and decide what to do about it, though it may not really matter all that much depending on what you're modeling. Here you have three variables that pass that cutoff, so it will help to inspect them and see what is going on before deciding if action needs to be taken.
Interestingly, some have argued abandoning VIF altogether (Kalnins & Hill, 2023) and the cutoff for GVIF and GVIF transformations isn't totally resolved. There is also this Quantitude episode which does a good job of explaining why collinearity may or may not matter in the grand scheme of things if we are chiefly concerned with the VIF. It tends to matter most for cases when you have something like perfect or near perfect collinearity, where two variables are essentially contributing the same thing to the model. A good example in Statistical Rethinking (McElreath, 2020) is his example of "collinear legs", where predicting height based off your left leg length and right leg length essentially makes one of the predictors redundant. This can cause your standard errors to explode, making them very unreliable, and should be consequently corrected.
This is where plotting the data, understanding the causal relationships, etc. will help guide what you should do. This can include transforming predictors to be some combination (e.g. height and width into BMI) or removing one that isn't all that important (where here you have many anyway). Once you have some idea of what your predictors are contributing to the model from both a statistical and theoretical lens, it can be easier to discern what to do. A magic VIF/GVIF cutoff doesn't alone cut it.
References

Kalnins, A., & Praitis Hill, K. (2023). The VIF Score. What is it Good For? Absolutely Nothing. Organizational Research Methods, 10944281231216381. https://doi.org/10.1177/10944281231216381
McElreath, R. (2020). Statistical rethinking: A Bayesian course with examples in R and Stan (2nd ed.). Taylor and Francis, CRC Press.
Miles, J. (2014). Tolerance and variance inflation factor. WileyStatsRef: Statistics Reference Online. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/9781118445112.stat06593

